# How to get proper detailed debug messages in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to debug my VueJs3 application. Often I find that the debug messages shown in the console are cryptic and non-specific. This is an example of what I recently received:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:958 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emitsOptions')
    at shouldUpdateComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:958)
    at updateComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4448)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4402)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3993)
    at patchBlockChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4307)
    at patchElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4215)
    at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4073)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3990)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4608)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
```

Unfortunately these messages do not help narrow down the specific component or line where an object is null. In fact these lines dont reference any of my files. I do have Vue Chrome extension installed, but that doesn't show any debug information. I'm used to working with python/django where an exception triggers a beautiful cascade of stack trace which helps to easily debug errors. How can I be more productive in solving errors in Vue?